# How to retrieve SQL Agent failsafe operator email?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I want to find the email of the failsafe SQL Server Agent operator.

Usually I use this query :

```
DECLARE @TARGET nvarchar(255);
IF @OPERATOR_CONTACT IS NULL
   exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread 
      N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
      N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', 
      N'AlertFailSafeEmailAddress', 
      @param = @TARGET OUT, 
      @no_output = N'no_output';
```

But this query does not work on all SQL Server instances...

Did anyone has a more generic query to obtain this information ?

Comment: See if this helps. https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/601/

Comment: @SQLworldWide not the thing I want, but a little approach... How to do this for the instance I am in ? (the script does not work on W10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.alertsystem.failsafeemailaddress?view=sql-smo-160&viewFallbackFrom=sqlserver-2016) to do this in Powershell or C#

```
$srv = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]::new("YourServerName\YourInstanceName");

$srv.JobServer.AlertSystem.FailSafeEmailAddress;
```

Comment: I must do that in a stored procedure.... not in an application

Comment: @SQLpro CLR? Such means would allow you to leverage the above in C# code within the context of a stored procedure.

Comment: @J.D. of course C# possible, but some database won't accept to use SQL CLR just for that... !

Comment: Or use an External Script https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/csharp-overview?view=sql-server-ver16 either way this type of management should be done by sysadmin anyway so security is a moot point.